# Ordering of Title and Meta tag when using Yii Framework

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, yii, seo

Hi I am working on Yii 1x Framework. I have used the approach mentioned http://www.apurbadebnath.com/blog/yii-how-to-set-up-page-title-and-meta-description-from-yii-controller/
in this following Link.

The issue I am facing is that the Title Tag present in my View is appearing after the meta tags i've registered using Yii Controller. From SEO point of it is important that I get Title before the meta tags (desc and keyword). Please is there any solution for the above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. From documentation:

> Registers a meta tag that will be inserted in the head section (right
>   before the title element) of the resulting page.

I suggest declaring all necessary meta params as variables in parent controller and setting them in children appropriately.

```
$this->meta_param_1 = 'test';
$this->meta_param_2 = 'test';
```

Then setting them in your layout like this:

```
<title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
<meta name="meta_param_1" content="<?php echo CHtml::encode($this->meta_param_1); ?>" />
<meta name="meta_param_2" content="<?php echo CHtml::encode($this->meta_param_2); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I discovered this earlier but it is a bit tiring procedure if you are working on a huge application with multiple controllers and meta tags.